# asp.net WEB API, BufferedMediaTypeFormatter -> WriteToStream Data Loss?

Tags: asp.net, csv, asp.net-web-api, stream

I have created my custom CSV media type formatter following these two tutorials:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/creating-custom-csvmediatypeformatter-in-asp-net-web-api-for-comma-separated-values-csv-format

And it work fine, if not one problem:

I am not getting the hole data on csv file.

[image]

and on my csv i am getting 172 lines:

[image]

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who find the "data loss" problem when using [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): This is the fix i have found:

```
 myStreamWriter.AutoFlush = true;
```